# iOs in app chat

Tags: php, iphone, mysql

So I have an app that includes peer to peer chat, which is only between two users at a time.  What I am doing now is upon the user typing a new message, it calls a PHP script which inserts the message into a mysql table.  then every 5 seconds the code calls a php script which downloads all the messages.  So there is a maximum 10 second gap between messages.  So my question is if there is a better way to do peer to peer chat.

Comment: You probably want to look into Sockets. [PHP example](http://www.flynsarmy.com/2010/05/php-web-socket-chat-application/), [another](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash8/php5sockets_flash8.htm), [iOS app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the server as a matchmaker - use it only to find the other phone. You provide the IP address so that one phone can contact the other phone and initiate a connection. One of the phones act as a chat server.

You can read about sockets programming with Cocoa for example here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

Comment: is it possible you could give me a link for phone to phone communication?  Wouldn't I still have to poll for incoming connections?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to a sockets tutorial. The tutorial walks you through creating a HTTP server, but you can learn what you need to know from this tutorial.

Comment: You don't need to poll. delegate functions will be invoked

Answer (score 0):

You can check out something like IP Messaging with Twilio.

In the iOS quickstart (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-ios) you can try it out in Objective-C or Swift.

The server side app there (in PHP) manages identity and access tokens for the application and the simple/example UI you end up with is this:

[image: The final product in a simple UI]

[*Note: I work for Twilio*]